# SMTP IIS getting 452 status

Tags: iis, smtp

I'm receiving emails on a Win 2008 R2 server via SMTP. Some of the emails are rejected with status 452, while others are accepted. I've disabled all size limits, including drop disk quota, but the problem remains.

What I noticed is the log records are slightly different for the 452 messages:

> MAIL - +FROM:<email@sender.com>+SIZE=1578 452 8 25 50 0 SMTP
>
> MAIL - +FROM:<email@sender.com> 250 0 53 50 0 SMTP

In other words, the failing messages have a SIZE extension in the log, although some of them originate from the same address as the ones that pass.

Please help me to troubleshoot this.

Comment: 4xx are temporary,  do they eventually go through?

Comment: I'm not sure if the new records are attempts to deliver the same message, but no, they don't.